# Bootstrap typeahead select event for a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Good day. I'm starting to use the bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js version 4.0.2, and it's doing good, it works very well. My Twitter-Bootstrap version is 3.3.7.

So, as I understand, I have to use a special typeahead script, since this version doesn't have one.

Searching here, and other pages, I found the script in which, when I select the option I want, it automatically triggers the form, though it doesn't work, it only puts the value of the search on the input. Tried putting a console.log, but, it doesn't trigger it either.
Here is the online script of the twitter-bootstrap3 typeahead:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#valor').typeahead({
source: function(query, result)
{
 $.ajax({
  url:"mySearchUrl.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:{query:query},
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(data)
   {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
     return item;       
   }));   
  }
 })
}
 }).on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
  console.log("hello");
  e.target.form.submit();
 });
});
```

Here is my form:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" id="form_buscar" name="form_buscar" method="post" action="myurl.php">
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Buscar nombre, credito o calle" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" name="buscar" id="buscar" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Everything works really well, except the part where the selected event.

Also, I have read about this other script, but I can't seem to make it work either:

```
 $('#valor').on('typeahead:select', function(evt, item) {
    console.log(evt)
    console.log(item)

})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the event is `typeahead:select` not `typeahead:selected`

Comment: thanks for responding, I changed it, but it still doesn't work. I even changed the e.target.form.submit(); to the id of the form, but, nothing.

Comment: I'd replace the ajax call with some static data.  start simple. make sure it works before adding complexity.

Comment: the ajax call works, there's nothing wrong with that. It's the typeahead select event that I can't get to work :S

Comment: I never said it didn't, just making a suggestion to start with one of their simple examples.  If you can get that to work as expected then it should be a simple matter to substitute the ajax call

Comment: Oops, sorry, I changed my code for a sample one, it searches, but doesn't submit, so the on typeahead select doesn't work or it changed in a newer version :S , `[{"id":"222","name":"sneha","employee_salary":"100000","employee_age":"23"}];


var $input = $("#valor");
  $input.typeahead({
    source: data,
    autoSelect: true
  }).on('typeahead:select', function(e){
    console.log("hello");
         e.target.form.submit();

   }); `